# Docker-compose executes django twice

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am running in windows 10, and trying to set up a project via docker-compose and django.

If you are interested, It will take you 3 minutes to follow this tutorial and you will get the same error as me. docs.docker.com/samples/django –

When I run

```
docker-compose run app django-admin startproject app_settings .
```

I get the following error

```
CommandError: /app /manage.py already exists. Overlaying a project into an existing directory won't replace conflicting files.
```

Or when I do this

```
docker-compose run app python manage.py startapp core
```

I get the following error

```
CommandError: 'core' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an 
app name. Please try another name.
```

Seems like the command is maybe executed twice? Not sure why?

Docker file

```
    FROM python:3.9-slim
    
    ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
    ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
    
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install
    
    RUN apt-get install -y \
        libpq-dev \
        gcc \
        && apt-get clean
    
    COPY ./requirements.txt .
    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
    
    RUN mkdir /app
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY ./app /app
```

Docker-compose

```
version: "3.9"

  compute:
    container_name: compute
    build: ./backend
    # command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    # volumes:
      # - ./backend/app:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: It seems like there's already a Django application in the container (you already have a `requirements.txt` file to copy in and the error suggests `manage.py` already exists); do you actually need to repeat these steps?  Are you getting inconsistent behavior by hiding the image's `/app` directory with a volume mount?

Comment: I did remove  `command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./backend/compute:/compute` and error still presists. I did delete the containers. How can I fix this already exist error?

Comment: You don't need to run `django-admin startproject` at all because the project already exists.

Comment: @DavidMaze how is it possible that the project exists? I have not created it anywhere. The first time I do create it is through django-admin startproject

Answer (score 0):

Try running your image without any arguments, you are already using the `command` keyword in your docker-compose or just remove that line from the file.

Comment: yes I did remove it. and deleted the containers and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Check if your project and app have the same name, if so, change the name

Comment: my project is called backend and the app is called core and the other is called compute.

Comment: I really don't like the way you are running your image. Did you build it ?
 What's the output of `docker ps -a` and `docker image -a`

Comment: sorry mate, there is no other image running. There must be some bug somewhere, I am downgrading everything and testing.

Comment: It will take you 3 minutes to follow this tutorial and you will get the same error as me.
https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/

Comment: also feel free to remove `command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` part and see it is still same message